# Should we promote good questions on the Tor Weekly Newsletter?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

The Tor Project releases a weekly update on both [a mailing list](https://lists.torproject.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/tor-news) and [the blog](https://blog.torproject.org/category/tags/tor-weekly-news), summarising what's happened in terms of development and the community.

The newsletter is [written](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/TorWeeklyNews) by volunteers from the developers and the Tor community, and they welcome new contributors.

I feel that being represented on the newsletter, not necessarily every week but hopefully on a regular basis, would be a huge benefit.

I don't anticipate it being a lot of work, but something along the lines of "On Tor.SE, X asked 'Y'", with a link to Tor.SE, and the question in particular. This could easily fit in with the Miscellaneous Items section.

Does anyone have any thoughts on this? (Volunteering to take this on yourself would be greatly appreciated!)

Comment: I was on the presumption that the weekly newsletter selected "hot", "good" and "popular not answered" questions already... did it not?

Comment: We're discussing the Tor Weekly Newsletter, which is organised by The Tor Project (and volunteers), not the Stack Exchange newsletter, which is entirely separate and run by different people..

Comment: OHHH! Nice. Didn't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I started to add some questions to the last editions of TWN. If you want to contribute, [search for twn](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/search?q=twn) in [Tor's trac](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor). You find the current edition at https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/TorWeeklyNews/2014/ plus the number of the current week. The document will be frozen at noon of each Tuesday.

Comment: Excellent news!

Answer (score 7):

Yes! They already do a help desk roundup, this would be about the same thing. I'd be happy to curate.

Great idea!

Comment: This is a great way to earn the [Announcer](http://tor.stackexchange.com/help/badges/59/announcer), [Booster](http://tor.stackexchange.com/help/badges/60/booster), and [Publicist](http://tor.stackexchange.com/help/badges/61/publicist) badges too, which are signs that a community has users sharing content and getting results! Just make sure you use the "share" links under the questions to get credit. :D)

Comment: That's an excellent point @jmort253 - I hadn't even considered that aspect!